# django Models One Author to Multiples Books Relationship

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a relationship on Django on models.py one Author could be the writer of multiples books for a Bookshop project. Please find below how the models.py looks. I'm afraid is not working correctly. Thank you.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import  reverse
# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model): # books categories

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail',args=[self.slug])


class Product(models.Model): # books as products
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author,related_name='authors',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    book_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_index=True, blank=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)

    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail',args=[str(self.slug)])
      

class Author(models.Model): # book's author
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Comment: Define a `ForeignKey` to `Author` on the `Product` model and remove the `product` field on `Author`. You have the relationship the wrong way round

Comment: Can I have on the Product model two ForeignKey one with Category and another with Author? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can have as many foreign keys as you like

Comment: Excellent! Then I can just display one author and all his books. Correct?

Comment: Yup, if you have an author you can get all their books using `author.product_set.all()` by default

Comment: Excellent! I just made the changes to the code. Kindly review. Thank you.

Comment: Looks fine, though you probably want `related_name='products'` on the `author` field, having `author_obj.authors` refer to the author's products doesn't seem right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229077/discussion-between-nick-nick-and-iain-shelvington).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you construct a one-to-many is this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The foreign key will go into the child class as one parent can have multiple children but a child can have only one parent. So each child object with have a foreign key pointing to the parent.

Related name is usually the plural of the class that holds the foreign key (in this case 'children'). A model can have multiple foreign keys pointing to different models, for this example, the child might have 2 extra foreign keys for grandfather and a grandmother.

```
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```